# excel VBA to send e-mail from macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro to send an e-mail from an excel sheet. The macro prepares a few reports and then has a function to prepare the e-mail for the report. Everything works fine except when it gets to the .Send line it gives me a run time error -2147467259. Not sure what this means, but would appreciate the help.

Here is the code for the function:

```
Function Mail_Reports(ByRef wkDate2 As String, fileDate2 As String, wkNumber2 As String, thisYear2 As String)
' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, Outlook 2010.
' This example sends the last saved version of the Activeworkbook object .
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim mailList As String
    Dim i As Long, lstRow As Long, p As Long, addressNum As Long, begRow As Long
    Dim proNam2 As String
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    'On Error Resume Next
   ' Change the mail address and subject in the macro before you run it.
    For i = 1 To 5 Step 1
        mailList = ""
        lstRow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        addressNum = lstRow - 16
        begRow = lstRow - addressNum
        proNam2 = Sheets("Data").Cells(16, i)
        proNam2 = Replace(proNam2, " ", "")
        For p = 1 To addressNum Step 1
            mailList = Sheets("Data").Cells(begRow + p, i) & " ; " & mailList
        Next p
        With OutMail
            .To = mailList
            '.CC = "" remove comma and use this if you want to cc anyone, can be string or variable
            '.BCC = "" remove comma and use this if you want to cc anyone, can be string or variable
            .Subject = "Test"
            .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY><Font Face=Calibri(Body)><p>Hi All,</p><p2>Attached to this e-mail is the test file.<p2/><br><br><p3>Best,<p3/></font></BODY></HTML>"
            .attachments.Remove 1
            .attachments.Add "C:\Documents and Settings\test.xlsx"
            .Display
            .Send
    Next i


    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Are you sending a range, sheet, workbook?

Comment: If you don't use the .Send, but instead just use .Display, does your e-mail appear correct? If your first e-mail is sending fine, but subsequent ones aren't, see my answer below.

Comment: @bonCodigo I am sending a workbook, sorry.

Comment: @mkingston if I use .Display it appears correct but none of them send.

Comment: @Eric_S so have you tried the steps I have given you :) Once you get to send one book with most simplest way, then you can iterate to send the rest. Let me know if it had helped. Which version of Outlook are you using?

Comment: @Eric_S I don't mean to be rude at all, but I'm guessing you're a relatively novice coder. Take note of the reduction technique bonCodigo suggests, it's really a great way to debug some problems; i.e. by making the most simple case work then add things line by line and see what breaks.

Comment: @mkingston yea I am definitely glad he/she brought that up because now I know how to go about isolating where the issue might be. Very helpful, both of you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try with just,

1. Save the report file into a local drive
2. use one email address first, so remove the for loop
3. send it with just one file/range/workbook.
4. remove html tags for signature or etc..

Code:

```
With WB '-- workbook
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, _
                FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = "myname@myname.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
            .Body = "Here is a Report on My VBA analysis"
            .Attachments.Add Dest.FullName
            'You can add other files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\testmail.txt") '-- .xls
            .Send   'or use .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
```

- Update based on the comments with OP:

Looking at your email concat loop, you do not have to do it each time when a new book comes **UNLESS YOUR MAILING LIST DIFFERS FOR EACH WORKBOOK...**. You may take that loop out of the mail workbooks iteration.

```
For p = 1 To addressNum Step 1
    mailList = Sheets("Data").Cells(begRow + p, i) & " ; " & mailList
Next p
```

Comment: this worked, so I tried it with just the HTML and with just the FOR loop and it works with the HTML code but it doesn't work when I have the FOR loop involved...any idea on how to fix that? should I make another function for the loop?

Comment: @Eric_S let's keep the `html` away for now. Since this single sending work, let's save the books first and try to send it via the loop. Two things might be going wrong here.. `1.` That your receipeint email string might not be generating a compatible email list when iterating.. `2.` `html` is causing some issue..

Comment: So if you only have an issue of just concatenating the email list, that makes things simpler here.. :) So you have a loop to iterate for each workbook. Then I suggest you concat the email seperately. And try out to send the workbooks in the workbook loop. Infact see my update.

Comment: it was indeed number 1. I had an extra . in there that was throwing it off...everything seems to work now, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I can see here is that you do the following:

```
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
```

outside the send loop. You should move that here:

```
[...]
For p = 1 To addressNum Step 1
  mailList = Sheets("Data").Cells(begRow + p, i) & " ; " & mailList
Next p
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
[...]
```

I can't comment on your specific error because I don't know what data is going into your OutMail object. However, to help you debug, I recommend you:

1. Close the `With OutMail` block with an `End With`
2. Set a reference to Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library
3. Declare OutApp as Outlook.Application (`Dim OutApp as Outlook.Application`)
4. Declare OutMail as Outlook.MailItem (`Dim OutMail as Outlook.MailItem`)
5. Initialise OutApp as follows: `Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application`

The above are not necessary (except maybe closing your `With OutMail` block) but may help you to diagnose problems with your code.

Also note that if you're using a newer version of Outlook, other applications (Excel, Word, Access etc.) may be prevented from sending by security controls: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263084.

Comment: As to #1, I had End With in, must have dropped it off. as far as #2 I can only find refrence to Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Object Library in the list, is that my issue? do I need to install something?

Comment: Re: `End With` I thought that might've been the case. Outlook 12.0 library is absolutely fine; the version just depends on your version of Outlook. Sorry, I meant to mention that but must've forgotten. As I say, it's not a necessity, but it's a great help within the IDE.